# Ubuntu 12.04.1 Server error on apt-get update?

Tags: 12.04, updates, aptitude

I get errors when using sudo apt-get update or installing packages.

```
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease

Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease

Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'  
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Cute. Canada is a "small" geographic area. The Canadian mirrors are frequently inoperative or slow. For all of Canada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced this error after changing my ip address to static. When doing so I did not type the ips in write causing the server to not access internet.